# Showing dimension of each eigenspace is 1

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$T$ is a linear map on an $n$-dimensional vector space. Given, for some vector $v$, the set {$v, T(v), ...T^{n-1}(v)$} is linearly independent, then every eigenvalue of $T$ has only one eigenvector upto scalar multiplication.

Someone told me this might be easy using Jordan blocks but since I haven't learnt that yet, a solution without that would be appreciated.

My approach: From the given condition it is easy to see degree of the minimal polynomial of $T$ is same as that of it's characteristic polynomial. This implies both of them are equal, since the former divides the latter. If I can somehow show one of them splits into distinct linear factors I am done. I think I have to take the restriction of $T$ in an eigenspace and consider dimensionality somehow. I'm not sure.

Comment: Hmm... sounds familiar. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3861621/every-eigenvalue-of-t-has-only-one-corresponding-eigenvector-up-to-a-scalar-mu/3861788#3861788

Comment: It does, thanks!